# Series and Linear Algebra

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

I have been studying series and I noticed that the Taylor series converges to a function using a polynomial basis and the Fourier series converges to a function in a given interval using a trigonometrical basis.

I wonder what are other vector spaces that could work similarly, I mean, is there an exponential basis and formulas for its coefficients, etc?